# Elasticsearch sorting only by alphabetical not by numeric

Tags: php, sorting, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jdbc-river

I am having problem with sorting in PHP, here is my mapping:

```
{
  "jdbc": {
    "mappings": {
      "jdbc": {
        "properties": { 
          "admitted_date": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "dateOptionalTime"
          },
          "et_tax": {
            "type": "string"
          },  
          "jt_tax": {
            "type": "string"
          }, 
          "loc_cityname": {
            "type": "string"
          }, 
          "location_countryname": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "location_primary": {
            "type": "string"
          },  
          "pd_firstName": {
            "type": "string"
          } 
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I use order the result by sort, it will order the results with alphanumeric, it will load the results with numeric as first. I need to order the results only starting letter alphabets.  Now it orders like this:

> `http://localhost:9200/jdbc/_search?pretty=true&sort=pd_lawFirmName:asc`
>
> 1. BM&A
> 2. Gomez-Acebo & Pombo
> 3. Addleshaw Goddard

How to order the results like this?

> 1. Addleshaw Goddard
> 2. BM&A
> 3. Gomez-Acebo & Pombo

Here is my query i using for indexing

```
{
    "type" : "jdbc",
    "jdbc" : {
        "driver" : "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
        "url" : "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname",
        "user" : "user",
        "password" : "pass",
        "sql" : "SQL QUERY",
        "poll" : "24h",
        "strategy" : "simple", 
        "scale" : 0,
        "autocommit" : true,
        "bulk_size" : 5000,
        "max_bulk_requests" : 30,
        "bulk_flush_interval" : "5s",
        "fetchsize" : 100,
        "max_rows" : 149669,
        "max_retries" : 3,
        "max_retries_wait" : "10s",
        "locale" : "in",
        "digesting" : true,
        "mappings": {
        "sorting": {
        "properties": { 
        "pd_lawFirmName": {
        "type": "string",
        "fields": {
          "raw": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          }
        }
      }
      }
    }
  }
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/sorting-collations.html

Comment: Yes, But it orders the result from last word, here is the example  `pd_lawFirmName: "McDermott Will Amery",`  `sort: ["amery"]` . but the first letter is `M`

Answer (score 2):

This is like that because Elasticsearch will tokenize the text using the default analyzer, which is `standard`. For example, `McDermott Will Amery` is indexed like:

```
              "amery",
              "mcdermott",
              "will"
```

If  you want to sort like that, I would suggest to change the mapping of your `pd_lawFirmName` in something like this:

```
  "pd_lawFirmName": {
    "type": "string",
    "fields": {
      "raw": {
        "type": "string",
        "index": "not_analyzed"
      }
    }
  }
```

and sort by the `raw` subfield:

```
http://localhost:9200/jdbc/_search?pretty=true&sort=pd_lawFirmName.raw:asc
```

Comment: I got following error when i use the URL   `error: "SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed; shardFailures {[U8fk4Ih3SOGSsl0p_aY8ww][jdbc][0]: SearchParseException[[jdbc][0]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"sort":[{"pd_lawFirmName.raw":{"order":"asc"}}]}]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[jdbc][0]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [No mapping found for [pd_lawFirmName.raw] in order to sort on]]; }`

Comment: Have you changed the mapping as I suggested?

Comment: yes, here is my query `{....,"mappings": { "sorting": { "properties": {           "pd_lawFirmName": { "type": "string", "fields": { "raw": { "type": "string",           "index": "not_analyzed" } } } } }}}}`

Comment: Your initial mapping - `jdbc` - doesn't look anything like what you provided now. Update your post and provide the exact mapping you have **now** and the exact query you tested.

Comment: I meant the actual mapping in Elasticsearch: `GET /jdbc/_mapping`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93454/discussion-between-satheesh-and-andrei-stefan).